# How do you append a dynamic script with php variable inside and render the variable?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I am trying to place a stripe checkout button on a form with a dynamic amount to be charged based on the user's selection. The checkout button is rendered from Javascript as described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple).

I am adding the script dynamically like so and used the answer to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761149/dynamically-added-script-will-not-execute) to execute it.

```
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute('src','https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js');
    script.setAttribute('class','stripe-button');
    script.setAttribute('data-key',"<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>");
    script.setAttribute('data-amount',parseFloat(jQuery('#totalCost').html())*100);
    script.setAttribute('data-description','Monthly subscription for ' + package_enabled);

    if(!document._write) document._write = document.write;
    document.write = function (str) {
        document.getElementById('paymentForm').innerHTML += str;
    };
    document.getElementById('paymentForm').appendChild(script);
```

The issue I am having is that the script does not render the php variable in this line

```
script.setAttribute('data-key',"<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>");
```

and just prints it out as string like so

```
data-key="&lt;?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?&gt;"
```

As a hack, I can enter the key directly but I'd rather not. Is there any other solution?

Comment: If you view the page source, do you see the php code in there or the output from the php in there?

Comment: That file would need to be parsed by PHP.  If the extension is .js or .html then probably not.

Comment: this one should get you moving - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: Yes @LatheesanKanes I see php code, like this data-key="&lt;?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?&gt;"

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes it's a tpl.php file