# When are dynamic scripts executed?

Tags: javascript, xss

I was doing the google XSS games (https://xss-game.appspot.com/level2), but I couldn't quite figure out why level 2 wasn't working the way I was expecting. Even though the hint says that script tags won't work, I didn't know why. My question is basically when are dynamic script tags executed and does this vary by browser?

I tried something simple as:

```
<script>alert();</script>
```

And while it adds the element to the page, it doesn't do what I had hoped.

I found this post which has the same problem, but the solution is just an answer, but not an explanation:
[Dynamically added script will not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761149/dynamically-added-script-will-not-execute)

Comment: I can tell you that adding `<script>` elements via `.innerHTML` does not execute them ;)

Answer (score 1):

If a site sanitizes only SCRIPT tags but allows other HTML - it opens itself to XSS. The hint in the Level 2 is text in the message window having some HTML formatting (italic, color etc.) so the assumption here - HTML tags are allowed.

So you can enter something like

```
<i>Hello Xss</i>
```

Into the message window to display text in italic. But a DOM element can have an event handler attached to it - you can include executable JavaScript into event handler without any SCRIPT tags.

Try entering this into message window:

```
<i onmouseover="alert(1)">Hello Xss</i>
```

and after submitting message wave mouse over your message text.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that `<script>` tags added via .innerHTML do not execute.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML :

> **Security considerations**
>
> It is not uncommon to see innerHTML used to insert text in a web page. This comes with a security risk.

```
var name = "John";
// assuming el is an HTML DOM element
el.innerHTML = name; // harmless in this case

// ...

name = "<script>alert('I am John in an annoying alert!')</script>";
el.innerHTML = name; // harmless in this case
```

> Although this may look like a cross-site scripting attack, the result is harmless. HTML5 specifies that a  tag inserted via innerHTML should not execute.
>
> However, there are ways to execute JavaScript without using  elements, so there is still a security risk whenever you use innerHTML to set strings over which you have no control. For example:

```
var name = "<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>";
el.innerHTML = name; // shows the alert
```