# How Can I Display This Popup When Clicked On A Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Script Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uid = 'xxxxx';
var wid = 'xxxxx';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.popcash.net/pop.js"></script>
```

Button Code:

```
<div>
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Get reward!">
</div>
```

I am a total noob at this..pls help !!

Comment: Where did you get the pop.js? Are you sure it dies what you expect?
Seems to be a script that runs itself...

Comment: It's the code of a popup ad..i've replaced my reference id with xxxxx

Comment: I Want This Script To Execute When The Button Is Pressed

Comment: Therefore, I would contact the developer of the popup, because i don't know this file and it is compressed so difficult to read. I'm sorry I can't help, but the developers should give you advanced help.

Comment: I could ... give you a solution, including the file right when the button is clicked, but it will work once and then the file is included and can't be included again (since you reload)

Comment: PLease Do Tell The Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to execute the script when the button is pressed, here is a way to do so:

```
<script>
  var uid = 'xxxxx';
  var wid = 'xxxxx';

  function showPopup() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://cdn.popcash.net/pop.js';

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
</script>

<div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Get reward!" onclick="showPopup();">
</div>
```

Although I must tell you that you should be aware of possibles security breaches that executing external javascript files may open. A similar case is found at [Dynamically added script will not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761149/dynamically-added-script-will-not-execute)

Comment: I don't fully recall, but I think I had it written down and then I was testing something related. When I came back I'd submitted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="alert('this is your msg.');" value="Get reward!">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" id="button1" value="Click Me" onclick="alertThis()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertThis(){
        var var1 = "xxxx";
        var var2 = "yyyy";
        alert(var1+var2);
    }
</script>
```

That should do it.

Comment: I Want TO Run The Above Provided Script

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uid = 'xxxxx';
var wid = 'xxxxx';
</script>
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Get reward!" onclick="addPopup()">
```

Your JS:

```
function addPopup() {
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.setAttribute('src', 'http://cdn.popcash.net/pop.js');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
}
```

This works, if the pop.js will init itself, when included

Comment: But u have not included my reference id ..how will it work ??

Comment: you should include it by yourself :D I just edited the button and added js code. But don't forget to remove the line where you include your pop.js

Comment: That's what i said. Maybe you make a function to remove tis line again and look if it works. Then you are able to include it again.