# onload event is not firing

Tags: javascript, onload

I've implemented this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16231055/5415084) in order to solve my problem but I still can't get the onload event fire.

I need a javascript solution, and I'm trying this on chrome. I know that I need to check for `readystate` for IE.

What am I missing here?

```
<script>
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = "type/javascript";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

        script.onload = function(){
            console.info("After loading");
            mdp.video.loadAllPlayers(".videoPlaceholder");
        };

        script.src = "/source.min.js";
</script>
```

Comment: Let me check out this, when I get back from lunch...

Comment: Are you getting any network errors?

Comment: You can write a script element but it will not execute unless you get the HTML parser to re-parse the document with that element in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically added script will not execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761149/dynamically-added-script-will-not-execute)

Comment: You need this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28002292/907047

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Something like that***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    var el = document.createElement('script');
    el.src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.3.3/less.min.js"; // use what ever js file you want but valid one
    el.onload = function(script) {
      console.log(script + ' loaded!');
    };

    document.body.append(el);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the major difference is but this works. I've change the `body` to `head`, tested and checked out. Thank you